# Gun don't spawn in the same place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a gun system and I need to pick up guns that I spawn
But the problem is that when I pick up gun it doesn't spawn in the place that I wanted because of the player rotation Here is a picture: https://netane54544-gmail.tinytake.com/media/75f9e3?filename=1525456534383_04-05-2018-08-53-27.png&sub_type=thumbnail_preview&type=attachment&width=1198&height=654

Also here is another picture of the guns, just to show what I'm going for:https://netane54544-gmail.tinytake.com/media/75f9f5?filename=1525456736315_04-05-2018-08-56-51.png&sub_type=thumbnail_preview&type=attachment&width=1198&height=654

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
foreach (Gun item in gunList)
    {
        if (item.gunType == "Normal" && guns_inInventory[playerScript.keyPress] == false)
        {
            playerGuns[playerScript.keyPress] = Instantiate(Weapon_Normal, Camera.main.transform.position + Normalview.offSetPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            playerGuns[playerScript.keyPress].name = gunName;
            playerGuns[playerScript.keyPress].transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
            playerGuns[playerScript.keyPress].transform.eulerAngles = Normalview.startOffsetRotation;
            setGunActive(playerScript.keyPress);

            //Store gundata in inventory
            item.Named = false;
            Inventory[playerScript.keyPress] = item;
            guns_inInventory[playerScript.keyPress] = true;
        }
        else if (item.gunType == "Stride" && guns_inInventory[playerScript.keyPress] == false)
        {
            playerGuns[playerScript.keyPress] = Instantiate(Weapon_Stride, Camera.main.transform.position + Normalview.offSetPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            playerGuns[playerScript.keyPress].name = gunName;
            playerGuns[playerScript.keyPress].transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
            playerGuns[playerScript.keyPress].transform.eulerAngles = Strideview.startOffsetRotation;
            setGunActive(playerScript.keyPress);

            //Store gundata in inventory
            item.Named = false;
            Inventory[playerScript.keyPress] = item;
            guns_inInventory[playerScript.keyPress] = true;
        }
    }
```

I tryed to find the problem but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NormalView.offSetPosition` only stores the displacement when there is no rotation.

For example, suppose your `offsetPosition` is Vector (0, 0, 1):

`Camera.main.transform.position + NormalView.offSetPosition` will take the camera's position and ALWAYS add Vector (0, 0, 1) which is effectively 1 unit forward on the world axis, effectively ignoring the rotation of the camera.

To solve this, change your instantiation position to:

```
Camera.main.transform.position + 
(Camera.main.transform.forward * NormalView.offSetPosition.z) +
(Camera.main.transform.right * NormalView.offSetPosition.x) +
(Camera.main.transform.up * NormalView.offSetPosition.y)
```

This takes into account the rotation of the camera by getting the camera's foward/right/up vector which is affected by its rotation. By multiplying it with your offset (distance in that direction) it will always spawn at the same location relative to your character regardless of the camera's rotation.